# Questions about concurrent & interrupted UMONITOR/UMWAIT behaviors

Tags: multithreading, assembly, x86, intel, instructions

UMONITOR & UMWAIT instruction for supported Intel x86 processors can be very useful waiting for short period of time in userspace without kernel transition overhead while waiting for shared memory or MMIO variables.

However, some of the description in the instruction manuals are not clear to me and they are mostly about their behavior in concurrency, multiprocessor, and timer/IPI interrupts.

(all of the below questions expect Linux-based environment)

1. [The UMONITOR instruction manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umonitor) states:

   > UMONITOR does not interoperate with the legacy MWAIT instruction. If UMONITOR was executed prior to executing MWAIT and following the most recent execution of the legacy MONITOR instruction, MWAIT will not enter an optimized state. Execution will continue to the instruction following MWAIT.

   The above can be interpreted that any MONITOR, or MWAIT not in execution will be invalid if UMONITOR intervenes between MONITOR and the subsequent MWAIT.

   Also, [the UMWAIT instruction manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait) states:

   > A store to the address range armed by the UMONITOR instruction will cause the processor to exit UMWAIT if either the store was originated by **other** processor agents or the store was originated by a non-processor agent.

   Will each `UMONITOR` executed in concurrent user threads running be independent from each other for (1) if they are not scheduled to same processor core, or (2) NUMA node? Or is it always valid for 3) any cases, i.e. if there is not subsequent `UMONITOR` (& `MONITOR` described below) executed in the same user thread, it will be valid?
2. [The UMWAIT instruction manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait) states:

   > ... The UMWAIT instruction will not wait (will not enter an
   > implementation-dependent optimized state) if any of the following
   > instructions were executed before UMWAIT and after the most recent
   > execution of UMONITOR: IRET, MONITOR, SYSEXIT, SYSRET, and far RET
   > (the last if it is changing CPL).
   >
   > The following additional events cause the processor to exit the
   > implementation-dependent optimized state: a store to the address range
   > armed by the UMONITOR instruction, an NMI or SMI, a debug exception, a
   > machine check exception, the BINIT# signal, the INIT# signal, and the
   > RESET# signal. Other implementation-dependent events may also cause
   > the processor to exit the implementation-dependent optimized state.
   >
   > In addition, an external interrupt causes the processor to exit the
   > implementation-dependent optimized state regardless of whether
   > maskable-interrupts are inhibited (EFLAGS.IF =0).
   >
   > Following exit from the implementation-dependent-optimized state,
   > control passes to the instruction after the UMWAIT instruction. A
   > pending interrupt that is not masked (including an NMI or an SMI) may
   > be delivered before execution of that instruction.
   >
   > Unlike the HLT instruction, the UMWAIT instruction does not restart at
   > the UMWAIT instruction following the handling of an SMI.
   >
   > If the preceding UMONITOR instruction did not successfully arm an
   > address range or if UMONITOR was not executed prior to executing
   > UMWAIT and following the most recent execution of the legacy MONITOR
   > instruction (UMWAIT does not interoperate with MONITOR), then the
   > processor will not enter an optimized state. Execution will continue
   > to the instruction following UMWAIT.

   1. If 1-(1) does not matter, and since the timer interrupt for scheduler is not the one of interrupt types described above, will the context switching by timer interrupt, other IPI disarm the previous `UMONITOR` execution for that user thread evicted? Or, will the monitoring-related MSRs be restored to continue? If the later is true, would the rearming miss any previous updates  during the disarmed period for subsequent UMWAIT (already executed or not yet)?
   2. Will UMWAIT be interrupted (i.e.resume to execute next instruction) if the bus monitoring set by previous UMONITOR gets disabled, or until OS/user TSC timeout kicks in?
3. Does UMWAIT still act as hint for busy loop condition like PAUSE, even if the monitor arming fails?
4. Are multiple UMWAITs without subsequent UMONITOR executed still valid, if they are targetting the same address and the monitoring has not been disabled for any reason? Or, does UMWAIT only disarm the address snooping when the previous store on that address got caught during its execution time?

Comment: Regarding 4: I bet `umwait` is similar to `mwait` so No. Intel explicitly states that `monitor/mwait` must come in pairs. Regarding 3: I highly doubt so, two very different mechanisms are involved. Regarding 2: the timer interrupt is an external interrupt, and so is an IPI I think. I don't understand 1. I think of the HW monitor as having two states: unarmed and armed. `(u)monitor` set it to armed, `(u)mwait` wait until it's different from `armed` and any event sets it back to unarmed.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thank you so much for your comment! It is very helpful. About the answer regarding my question #4: Does `(u)monitor` and `(u)mwait` pair must be `exactly` adjacent, or is it just fine to let there be something else between them? About Q#1 and Q#2, I think it is problematic that due to whatever reason, `(u)mwait` can always fail and it is hard to predict specially in userspace.

Comment: When umwait is used to monitor a memory address, there always has to be a test between the umonitor and the umwait to check whether the condition is satisfied, otherwise there is a race (between the memory location being written and the umonitor).

Comment: @hurryman2212: In correctly written code (ignoring a buggy kernel doing a mismatched "monitor then uwait" and a buggy user-space program doing "umonitor then kernel system call then uwait")' for `(u)wait` to always fail you'd need an external event (IRQ, NMI, SMI, ...) to always occur between the `(u)monitor` and the `(u)wait`; and in that case you've got severe problems (100% CPU load from handling the external event alone) and won't be worried about the `(u)wait` (in the same way that you don't worry about a splinter in your finger while you're being eaten by a shark). ;-)

Comment: @hurryman2212: Also note that for correct code you must have a busy loop (perhaps crudely like `if( something_not_happened) { monitor(something); do { mwait(); monitor(something); } while( something_not_happened); }`) to guard against false wake-ups; and if anything disarms the trigger between `(u)monitor` and `(u)mwait` you get an extremely tiny reduction in power savings corresponding to the time it takes to re-arm and retry, which is almost always inconsequential (excluding the "100% CPU load handling external events" problem).

Comment: @Brendan For the later answer, for `do { mwait(); monitor(); } while (eval);`, does monitor has to be called at the last step of loop, even if eval can be true? Also, how can I check (without overhead) that there was external event between `(u)monitor` and `(u)mwait` so the monitoring disarmed?

Comment: @Brendan I do use `UMWAIT` and `PAUSE` only for busy loop optimization, but also  for something like `while (!eval) { foo(); umonitor(...); if (!eval) umwait(...); }` or  `while (!eval) { foo(); _mm_pause(); }`.

Comment: @hurryman2212: D'oh. I messed up my previous example and it should've been `monitor(something); if( something_not_happened) { do { mwait(); monitor(something); } while( something_not_happened); }`.  In general, you need "monitor then test (then mwait)" to avoid the race condition @prl mentioned (e.g. to avoid "test, then the memory changes, then you monitor something that already changed, then you mwait for ages even though it already changed"). You can `do { mwait(); if(!eval) monitor(); } while (eval);` but it adds higher overhead to every iteration to avoid a final cheaper `monitor()` so...

Comment: @hurryman2212: It's impossible to check for "disarmed before mwait" without race conditions (the monitor being disarmed after you checked and before the mwait); and any possible check (to opportunistically avoid the cost of mwait) will be slower than just doing the mwait.

Comment: I would write it as `while (!eval()) { monitor(); if (eval()) break; mwait(); }`. It just seems more straightforward to me, but essentially equivalent to what @Brendan has written.  You have to perform the eval in two places, after the monitor and after the mwait, it can't be avoided.